# MYSQL query with UNION works in local Xampp but not in the production

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have MariaDB 10.4.17 in my local xampp environment. In my production environment, I have MySQL 5.7.28. As the query didn't work, I tried another server with MariaDB 10.3.31, Thinking it is not working in the production version because the server type is "MySQL"

I dumped the whole database and imported it to both the servers, and ran the exact same query in all three servers. Also, I imported the same dump file to the local host making another database thinking it could be an issue when exporting the database. But the query worked perfectly on that local database as well.

I'm actually clueless on this now. Some help would be highly appreciated.

Below is the query I'm trying.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS AGGREGATE
FROM
    `ps_servers`
WHERE
    (
        (`created_by` = 4) OR(
            created_by IN(
            SELECT
                id
            FROM
                users
            WHERE
                parent_id = 4
            UNION
        SELECT
            U.id
        FROM
            users U
        LEFT JOIN users T ON
            U.parent_id = T.id
        ) AND server_type = 'PUBLIC' OR server_type = 'PRIVATE'
        ) OR(
            created_by IN(
                (
                SELECT
                    parent_id
                FROM
                    users
                WHERE
                    id = 4
                UNION
            SELECT
                T.parent_id
            FROM
                users U
            LEFT JOIN users T ON
                U.parent_id = T.id
            WHERE
                U.id = 4
            )
        UNION
            (
            SELECT
                A.parent_id
            FROM
                users U
            LEFT JOIN users T ON
                U.parent_id = T.id
            LEFT JOIN users A ON
                T.parent_id = A.id
            WHERE
                U.id = 4
        )
            ) AND server_type = 'PUBLIC'
        )
    ) AND `server_type` = 'PUBLIC' AND `status` <> 'DELETED'
```

The error I'm getting in the MYSQL server is this

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'UNION
> (
> SELECT
> A.parent_id
> ' at line 42

The error I'm getting in the Maria DB is

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'UNION
> (
> SELECT
> A.parent_id
> ...' at line 42

Comment: What  mean "query not work"? If you got error please post it here. If you got wrong data please post test data here [mre]

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev, Hi sorry about that, I forgot to add the error. Now I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: It would be best if you use the same brand and version of database software in development and production, to avoid compatibility surprises like this. MySQL and MariaDB have a common origin circa 2010, but they both have changed significantly since then, and they should no longer be considered to be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. it was just an issue with the additional brackets I used.
I removed the surrounding brackets near Union keyword. Now it is working. here is the updated query if anyone is curious about it.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS AGGREGATE
FROM
    `ps_servers`
WHERE
    (
        (`created_by` = 4) OR(
            created_by IN(
            SELECT
                id
            FROM
                users
            WHERE
                parent_id = 4
            UNION
        SELECT
            U.id
        FROM
            users U
        LEFT JOIN users T ON
            U.parent_id = T.id
        ) AND server_type = 'PUBLIC' OR server_type = 'PRIVATE'
        ) OR(
            created_by IN(
            SELECT
                parent_id
            FROM
                users
            WHERE
                id = 4
            UNION
        SELECT
            T.parent_id
        FROM
            users U
        LEFT JOIN users T ON
            U.parent_id = T.id
        WHERE
            U.id = 4
        UNION
    SELECT
        A.parent_id
    FROM
        users U
    LEFT JOIN users T ON
        U.parent_id = T.id
    LEFT JOIN users A ON
        T.parent_id = A.id
    WHERE
        U.id = 4
        ) AND server_type = 'PUBLIC'
        )
    ) AND `server_type` = 'PUBLIC' AND `status` <> 'DELETED'
```